# phpInfo: What does "Virtual Server" refer to?

Tags: apache2, php, virtual-server

I noticed that in phpinfo under "apache2handler", it says:

> Virtual Server    Yes

What does that refer to?  Does that mean that apache is on a virtual (i.e. not dedicated) host?  What would be a case when it would say:

> Virtual Server    No

?

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That really just means that apache is configured so that it can [serve more than one domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting).  It has nothing to do with whether or not apache is running on a [shared server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_web_hosting_service) or dedicated server.

Similar terminology, completely different meanings.

Comment: Ok, thought so.  Thank you for confirming.